# How can you disable the Skype Alerts (status updates) Screen?

Tags: skype

When first opened the left sidebar shows a list of contacts/recent conversation, whilst the main pane shows a "How to make free voice and video calls" video, an advert for their Facebook integration, and a recent history of my contacts' status updates.

Is there a way to hide this main pane? It slows down the load time of Skype (particularly when there's a bad connection), and for me adds no value.

I'm running Skype v7.

Comment: I am almost certain that if you purchase credits the ads go away.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound.  I have £10 credits and only see Skype adds - not too bothered by ads themselves though - the main thing is the main pane is a waste of screen real estate and a performance overhead but gives no value (to me).

Comment: Text or a larger then needed interface has literally no overhead were talking about hundreds of Kbytes difference